# Error in Foursquare api java library

Tags: java, foursquare

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/wallabyfinancial/foursquare-api-java) to call the foursquare api. Foursquare recommend this library for [java users](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries).

But return the following error:

```
fi.foyt.foursquare.api.FoursquareApiException:     org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["icon"] not a string.
at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseEntity(JSONFieldParser.java:140)
at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseValue(JSONFieldParser.java:191)
at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseEntity(JSONFieldParser.java:138)
at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseEntities(JSONFieldParser.java:57)
at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.FoursquareApi.handleVenueSearchResult(FoursquareApi.java:969)
at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.FoursquareApi.venuesSearch(FoursquareApi.java:1017)
```

The code is the following:

```
    FoursquareApi foursquareApi = new FoursquareApi("foursquareClientId", "foursquareClientSecret", "foursquareUrlCallBack");
    Map<String, String> mapSearchParam = new HashMap<>();
    mapSearchParam.put("near", "ES");
    mapSearchParam.put("query", query);
    mapSearchParam.put("limit", "50");
    mapSearchParam.put("intent", "global");
    Result<VenuesSearchResult> venuesSearch = null;     
    venuesSearch = foursquareApi.venuesSearch("ES","mercadona",50,null,null,null,null,null);
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks!!

---

The problem is that the library is not updated:

https://github.com/ganchix/foursquare-api-java/tree/master

Comment: a had the same issue and I think you're right. They need to update the lib, or maybe you should be a contributor there ;)

Comment: https://github.com/clinejj/foursquare-api-java/commit/31b5aaa800e395d8891f77edb94ea11aeb1239f2