# fi.foyt.foursquare.api.FoursquareApiException: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["icon"] not a string

Tags: java

I am taking the foursquare sample java code and the same sample values from git and running in my local machine, but getting the following exception.
Here is my code:

```
String ll = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "44.3,37.2";

    try {
        FourSquareSampleMain fourSquareSample = new FourSquareSampleMain();
        fourSquareSample.searchVenues(ll);

    } catch (FoursquareApiException e) {
        // TODO: Error handling
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void searchVenues(String ll) throws FoursquareApiException {
    // First we need a initialize FoursquareApi.
    FoursquareApi foursquareApi = new FoursquareApi("CLIENT_ID",
            "CLIENT_SECRET", null);

    // After client has been initialized we can make queries.
    Result<VenuesSearchResult> result = foursquareApi.venuesSearch(ll, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (result.getMeta().getCode() == 200) {


        CompactVenue[] venueList = result.getResult().getVenues();
        System.out.println("Compact Venue List size : " + venueList.length);
        // if query was ok we can finally we do something with the data
        for (CompactVenue venue : venueList) {
            // TODO: Do something we the data
            System.out.println("Venue Name : " + venue.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("End of IF Loop: ");
    } else {
        // TODO: Proper error handling
        System.out.println("Error occured: ");
        System.out.println("  code: " + result.getMeta().getCode());
        System.out.println("  type: " + result.getMeta().getErrorType());
        System.out.println("  detail: " + result.getMeta().getErrorDetail());
    }
}
```

The size of the `venueList` is always "0", but when I debugged it , it throws the below exception:

> "org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array."

But strange when I changed the latitude and longitude value,

```
String ll = "-33.883056 , 151.216667";// latlong surry hills sydney
```

I get the below exception:

> fi.foyt.foursquare.api.FoursquareApiException: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["icon"] not a string.
>           at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseEntity(JSONFieldParser.java:143)
>           at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseValue(JSONFieldParser.java:194)
>           at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseEntity(JSONFieldParser.java:141)
>           at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseEntities(JSONFieldParser.java:57)
>           at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.FoursquareApi.venuesSearch(FoursquareApi.java:1017)
>           at FourSquareSampleMain.searchVenues(FourSquareSampleMain.java:57)
>           at FourSquareSampleMain.main(FourSquareSampleMain.java:43)
>       Caused by: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["icon"] not a string.
>           at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:658)
>           at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseValue(JSONFieldParser.java:202)
>           at fi.foyt.foursquare.api.JSONFieldParser.parseEntity(JSONFieldParser.java:141)

What am I missing here? please suggest.

Comment: same issue here...

Comment: Actually this issue is with an object either Venues or Items in the FourSquare API, so we have decided to use their endpoints instead of API, as we dont have enough time to raise and check with them. But with endpoint it is fin e for my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for that. It's a patch, but it works. Details:

1. Info was taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113867/error-in-foursquare-api-java-library) where same issue was identified and fixed
2. Take a look that diff that resolve the issue: https://github.com/wallabyfinancial/foursquare-api-java/compare/master...ganchix:master
3. Copy those 3 raw classes (Category, GeoCodeFeature and Icon) as they are and add them into your porject under the package `fi.foyt.foursquare.api.entities` and that's it

**Note 1**: when you replace classes (same package and class name) in yur project, the clasloader will use yours instead of the classes provided by the jar dependency, so, there is a quick fix.
I did that and it worked like a charm

**Note 2**: As soon as the sdk is updated, you should remove this patch and upgrade the sdk dependency

Hope it helps